# magento - get product count in search result page

Tags: magento

I want to get product count in search result and tag page
This code works on category page but not in search result and tag

```
$this->getLoadedProductCollection()->count();
```

I also checked this code and no result at all

```
$this->getCollection()->count();
```

I want to use it in list.phtml file

Answer (score 2):

Hello check this file

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalogsearch/result.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getResultCount(); ?>
```

Hope this help you...

Answer (score 1):

For search result page try below code:

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalogsearch')->__('<strong>%d item(s)</strong>', $this->getResultCount()); ?>
```

To get total number of products on catalog/product/list.phtml page use below code:

```
<?php $_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection(); 
$count = $_productCollection->getSize(); 
echo $count; ?>
```

Comment: thanks, but not working, returns 0 item(s), but there are 38 items :(

Comment: list.phtml, somewhere else should it be used ? i need it to just work in list.phtml

Comment: you mean catalog/product/list.phtml or any other custom list.phtml made by you ?

Comment: this file catalog/product/list.phtml, not a custom file

Comment: this code will return 8, which is my per page product show, i want to count all of products in result

Comment: in this file : product/list/toolbar.phtml
you can see : $this->getTotalNum(), which is the function i need, but how can i use it in list.phtml ?